# does a gesturerecognizer stay active when you leave and come back to that view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using this method to set a gesturerecognizer in several views.

```
- (void) setupNavbarGestureRecognizer {
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(navDoubleTap)];
    gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/4, 0, self.view.frame.size.width/2, 44);
    UIView *navBarTapView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar addSubview:navBarTapView];
    navBarTapView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [navBarTapView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [navBarTapView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    _navbarGestureActive = YES;
}
```

I noticed when I go to another view and come back and double tap in the main view, the program crashes.

So I did this:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [self setupNavbarGestureRecognizer];
}
```

I noticed that I didn't have to do the same in the other view controllers, only in the main view controller and only after it returned from another VC.

I'm concerned about loading the view and gestureRecognizer for this each time.  Clearly the old one is still active, because the crash is only on a double tap and that gestureRecognizer is the only one the recognizes that.

Somehow there is a disconnect between the gesturerecognizer and it's handler (navDoubleTap) and no delegates are used.

I should mention that it works fine in the main VC, until I leave and come back.

Update: The problem I ran into is that every time 'setupNavbarGestureRecognizer' is called, it adds a new view and gestureRecognizer.  This was done across several VCs and pointers were getting lost.

My solution was to delete the views and gestureRecognizers when entering and leaving each view, then call setupNavbarGestureRecognizer in viewWillAppear.

Maybe not the best approach, but it is working.

Comment: what is the crash, please include crash report as well

Comment: Yes it will crash, because you loose navBarTapView reference when you move to other controller. make navBarTapView as strong to hold its reference until the view controller is there.